# Sort implementer class methods in order they defined in interface

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In Visual Studio when I use Quick Actions(ctrl+.) and select implement interface it imports the methods in an alphabetical sort. But I want them to be imported in order that they defined in interface.

Is there a way to change this setting or any extension to do this?

Comment: In VS, there is no such setting to achieve custom sort. Maybe you can suggest a feature on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=8).

Comment: @KyleWang I sent a suggestion however it was suggested in [2018](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/406221/implement-interface-members-in-the-same-order-as-d.html)